# How do I make the content in a button move position in WPF, when I hover over the button?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button, hover

When I hover over a button in WPF (C#), I want the text in the button to move upwards to a different position, from the center to the top of the button, as an animation.

I currently have this XAML code for the style:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#c6c6c6"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="45"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalContentAlignment" To="Top" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

The problem is that in the DoubleAnimation (in StoryBoard), the To="Top" doesn't work, as it only wants a double value, I tried also just Changing the margin, to make the whole button move upwards, but that wouldn't work either. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#c6c6c6"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="45"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="contentMove"  X="0" Y="0"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentMove"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                             To="-10" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentMove"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                             To="-10" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentMove"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                             To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentMove"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                             To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>-->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Padding="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{DynamicResource MyButton}">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green"
                    Width="50" Height="50"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic solution that animates the content based on the button's actual size (and therefore allows the button to resize), you must extend `Button` to create a custom e.g. `AnimatedButton` type.

The following example only animates the content vertically from center to the top of the `AnimatedButton`.
To support more directions, you can introduce a custom `enum` that defines `Left, Top, Right, Bottom` and add corresponding offset calculations in this example (see code annotations):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <AnimatedButton Content="Animated content" />
</Window>
```

**AnimateButton.cs**

```cs
public class AnimatedButton : Button
{
  private UIElement ContentAnimationTargetElement { get; set; }
  private TranslateTransform ContentTranslateTransform { get; }
  private bool CanAnimateContent { get; set; }

  public AnimatedButton()
  {
    this.ContentTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    this.CanAnimateContent = false;

    /*** Find the content host ***/

    var visualChildren = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    DependencyObject firstChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0);
    visualChildren.Enqueue(firstChild);
    while (visualChildren.Any())
    {
      DependencyObject visualChild = visualChildren.Dequeue();
      if (visualChild is ContentPresenter contentPresenter)
      {
        this.ContentAnimationTargetElement = contentPresenter;
        this.CanAnimateContent = true;
        AttachRenderTransform(contentPresenter);

        break;
      }

      for (int visualChildIndex = 0; visualChildIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visualChild); visualChildIndex++)
      {
        DependencyObject childDescendant = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visualChild, visualChildIndex);
        visualChildren.Enqueue(childDescendant);
      }
    }
  }

  private void AttachRenderTransform(UIElement uiElement)
  {
    List<Transform> availableTransforms = new List<Transform>();

    // Anticipate and preserve existing transforms (from possible template overrides)
    switch (uiElement.RenderTransform)
    {
      case TransformGroup transformGroup:
        transformGroup.Children.Add(this.ContentTranslateTransform); break;
      case Transform transform:
        availableTransforms.Add(transform);
        availableTransforms.Add(this.ContentTranslateTransform);
        break;
      default:
        availableTransforms.Add(this.ContentTranslateTransform); break;
    }

    var transformCollection = new TransformCollection(availableTransforms);
    var newTransformGroup = new TransformGroup() { Children = transformCollection };
    uiElement.RenderTransform = newTransformGroup;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    if (!this.CanAnimateContent)
    { 
      return; 
    }

    // Get the current location of the content relative to the parent AnimatedButton
    GeneralTransform locationTransform = this.ContentAnimationTargetElement.TransformToVisual(this);
    Point currentAnimationTargetElementLocation = locationTransform.Transform(new Point());

    // This example only moves the content to the top of AnimatedButton (along the vertical axis).
    // The offset must be relative to the original content position (the locatin before the animation).
    //
    // TODO::If you want to support other animation directions e.g. Left, Right, Bottom,
    // then introduce a corresponding enum, a dependency property to set that enum
    // and a switch statement on the current value of that property.
    // Then based on the direction adjust the value of the 'finalContentLocation` variable below
    // and adjust the calculations of the offset e.g. positive or negative offset.
    Point finalContentLocation = new Point(currentAnimationTargetElementLocation.X, 0);
    double horizontalOffset = 0;
    double verticalOffset = finalContentLocation.Y - currentAnimationTargetElementLocation.Y;

    // Apply the animation based on the calculated offset
    AnimateContent(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    if (!this.CanAnimateContent)
    { 
      return; 
    }

    // The offset must be relative to the *original* content position (the location before the animation).
    double horizontalOffset = 0;
    double verticalOffset = 0;

    // Apply the animation based on the calculated offset

    AnimateContent(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
  }

  private void AnimateContent(double horizontalOffset, double verticalOffset)
  {
    var durationInMillieconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
    var contentAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(horizontalOffset, new Duration(durationInMillieconds), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    this.ContentTranslateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, contentAnimation);
    contentAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(verticalOffset, new Duration(durationInMillieconds), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    this.ContentTranslateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, contentAnimation);
  }
}
```